Retreive data from fillable PDF FILE with acrobatservices.adobe.com api
Hello stackoverflow community.
Hope you are all fine.
I need your help because i'm keeping gettting "Promise { : "rejected", : "Annotation APIs not enabled." }" with https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/view-sdk/viewer.js
My script aimed to retrieve user entered data from fillable PDF file. This is my script.


<script src="https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/view-sdk/viewer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function() {
            let res=null;
            var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "d146718832cf4e97afcd8b6e27fb967b", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
            
            adobeDCView.previewFile(
                {
                    content: {location: {url: "pdf.pdf"}},
                    metaData: {fileName: "Bulletin d'adhésion ",id: "aeef47fe-c473-4a6c-9e78-ec23d7790837"}
                }, 
                {
                    embedMode: "FULL_WINDOW",
                    defaultViewMode: "FIT_PAGE",
                    enableLinearization: true,
                    showDownloadPDF: true,
                    showPrintPDF: true,
                    showLeftHandPanel: false,
                    showAnnotationTools: false,
                    enableFormFilling: true,
                    enableAnnotationAPIs: true,
                    includePDFAnnotations: true,
                    showPageControls: false,
                    showZoomControl: true,
                    showRotateControl: false,
                    disableTextSelection: true,
                    annotationManagerEditMode: "READ",
                    showBookmarks:false,
                    showThumbnails:false,
                    
                }
            ).then((r)=>{
                    r.getAnnotationManager().then(function(a) {
                        console.log(a);
                        
                        a.getFormFields().then(function(f) {
                            console.log('Form Fields:', f);

                            const d = {};
                            f.forEach(r => {d[r.name] = r.value;});
                            console.log(d);
                            
                            
                        });
                    });

            }).catch((e)=>{
                    // Here i got error Promise { <state>: "rejected", <reason>: "Annotation APIs not enabled." }
                    console.log('res',e);
                    
            });
            
            
            document.getElementById('save-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
                    //Here i got adobeDCView.getAnnotationManager() is not a function
                    adobeDCView.getAnnotationManager().then(function(a) {
                        
                        a.getFormFields().then(function(f) {
                            const d = {};
                            f.forEach(r => {d[r.name] = r.value;});
                    }).catch((e)=>{
                    console.log('e',e);
                    
            });

            });
    });
</script>



